# Getting Foundation working with Laravel - no SCSS folder

Tags: laravel, zurb-foundation

I've been attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://somethingnewtutorial.blogspot.com/2017/07/using-foundation-6-with-laravel-5.html) to get Foundation working with Laravel 8, but I'm stuck on Step 4 because I don't have an SCSS folder at all in my Resources folder:

```
resources 
-- css
-- js
-- lang
-- views
```

Why is this, and how do I make sure I have all the necessary files and folders to continue following that guide and get Foundation working with Laravel?

Comment: It would be much easier and faster to just use the laravel presets.  https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/zurb-foundation

Comment: @jeremykenedy Thank you for that link, it looks promising, but how would I know whether I would also need `foundation-auth`? Can I use Laravel's auth without it?

Comment: It still uses laravel authentication scaffolding. It just swaps out the front end stuff and puts in the blade files needed.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Unfortunately that package doesn't seem to support Laravel 8, or even 7 - after grabbing all dependencies I run into an *Invalid preset* error. Until someone merges the PR from Aug 2020 it seems I'm stuck.

Comment: You can call the persons branch from your project that has the changes needed.

Comment: I can't believe it's such a convoluted process to get the second-biggest CSS framework working on PHP's biggest framework.

Comment: You mean like `composer require gucu112/zurb-foundation`? When trying that, I get `Could not find a matching version of package gucu112/zurb-foundation. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).`

Comment: The repo I'm trying to grab is here: https://github.com/gucu112/zurb-foundation/tree/gucu112/add-support-for-laravel-6.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-zurb

Comment: I forked a different repo and made the changes needed for it. Note in the example above I call my fork via the composer until the PR is accepted. https://github.com/jeremykenedy/foundation-for-laravel

Comment: @jeremykenedy Nice, I didn't know you could do that. I'll test now.

Comment: Let me know how it works out and any upvotes or answers marked as solved are greatly appreciated;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, do this (60 seconds install):

1. Add the following to your `composer.json`

```
    "dijitaq/foundation-for-laravel": "^1.2",

    ...

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://github.com/jeremykenedy/foundation-for-laravel.git"
        }
    ],
```

Which will look something like this when done:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "dijitaq/foundation-for-laravel": "^1.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://github.com/jeremykenedy/foundation-for-laravel.git"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

2. Run `composer update`
3. Run `composer require laravel/ui`
4. Run `php artisan ui bootstrap` * If you do not have the sass folder.
5. Run `php artisan foundation-ui --auth`
6. Run `npm install && npm run dev`

#### Here is a working example I put together for you:

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-zurb

#### Here is the Fork of the repo I made for the PR:

- https://github.com/jeremykenedy/foundation-for-laravel

#### Screenshots of the end result:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: This mostly works except that some of the fonts seem to be loading locally - it's trying to load the `Noto Sans JP` and `renogare` fonts locally. Any idea why that would be? Doesn't seem normal to reference local fonts without including them in the package itself.

Comment: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-zurb/blob/master/resources/sass/_settings.scss#L137

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. So it's normal for Foundation by default to load fonts locally without fallbacks? I figured something must be up with it.